# Operator on forms which commutes with correlated diffeomorphisms also commutes with Lie derivative along correlated vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M^m$ and $N^n$ be smooth manifolds and $\pi: M \rightarrow N$ be a submersion. Suppose we have some complete vector fields $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ and $Y \in \Gamma(TN)$ which are $\pi$-related.

Let $k \geq m-n$ and $A: \Omega^k(M) \rightarrow \Omega^{k-(m-n)}(N)$ be an $\mathbb R$-linear operator such that for any $\pi$-related diffeomorphisms $\phi: M \rightarrow M$ and $\psi:N \rightarrow N$, we have that $A \phi^* = \psi^* A$. I want to show that in this case, $L_Y (A\beta) = A (L_X \beta)$ for any $\beta \in \Omega^k(M)$.

(The particular case I'm interested in when $A = \pi_*$, integration on fibers, but I think beyond $A \phi^* = \psi^* A$ we needn't require $A$ to be particular.)

I denote by $\phi^X_t(x)$ the flow of $X$ through the point $x$ at time $t$ and similarly for $Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are $\pi$-related, $\phi^X_t$ and $\phi^Y_t$ are $\pi$-related. Then:

\begin{align*}
    L_Y (A \beta)_y &=
    \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \left[ (\phi^Y_t)^* (A \beta) \right]_{\phi^Y_{-t}(y)} - (A \beta)_y }{t} \\
    &=
    \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \left[ A ( (\phi^X_t)^* \beta)\right]_{\phi^Y_{-t}(y)} - (A \beta)_y }{t}\\
    &= \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{  \left[ \left( A ( (\phi^X_t)^* \beta) \right) \circ \phi^Y_{-t} \right]_y - (A \beta)_y }{t} \\
&= \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \left[  \left( A ( (\phi^X_t)^* \beta) \right) \circ \pi \circ \phi^X_{-t} \right]_x - (A \beta)_{\pi(x)} }{t}
\end{align*}

for some $\pi(x)=y$, the last equality following because $\pi \circ \phi_{-t}^X = \phi_{-t}^Y \circ \pi$. (To write the composition, I treated the form $A((\phi_t^X)^* \beta)$ as a function $N \rightarrow T^{(k,0)}N$).

After arriving here, I don't see how to pull $A$ out of the difference in the numerator.

Comment: Using $x\in N$, $y\in M$ and vector fields $X$ on $M$ and $Y$ on $N$ makes me give up immediately.

Comment: @TedShifrin In retrospect, such notational inelegance seems to have been espoused with the express purpose of irksomeness. Modified.